# Correct type for a function that sets individual properties of an object?

Tags: typescript

I have a settings object that has several different properties with different types. And I'm trying to write a function like the following:

```
update(settings, name, value)
```

that updates the property `name` on `settings` and sets it to `value`. My actual use case is a bit differnt, but this is the simplest version of the problem.

I'm having trouble getting Typescript to understand what I want to do here, and it's complaining about my code:

```
interface ISettings {
  string_setting: string;
  boolean_setting: boolean;
}

function updateSettings(
  oldSettings: ISettings,
  name: keyof ISettings,
  value: ISettings[keyof ISettings]
): ISettings {
  let newSettings: ISettings = { ...oldSettings };
  newSettings[name] = value;
  return newSettings;
}
```

on the line

```
  newSettings[name] = value;
```

I'm getting the error

> Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

VSCode tells me that `newSettings` is of the type ISettings, and `name` is of the type "string_setting" | "boolean_setting". So this looks like it's supposed to, but still throws an error.

The type for `value` is also not correct I think, as it is simply the union of all possible types for the properties on the settings object, it does not ensure that the value type matches the specific property selected by the name parameter.

Why is Typescript complaining about 'never' in my code? And what is the correct way to type the function I describe, ideally so strict that trying to assign a string to a boolean setting would fail?

Comment: you are trying to use `name` as a property and a property can only be a `string`. You are trying to use a `string` or a `boolean`, which is why you are getting a type `never`.

Comment: This will mean that if you change `name: ISettings` to `name: string` the error will go away.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn `name` is of the type `keyof ISettings`, so it's a string restricted to the actual keys present on that interface. I tried setting `name` to type string, and that doesn't fix the error, I just get a different one at the same place.

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstanding what you were trying to do, I understand now I think. I'm looking into it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translated to plain english, the signature

```
function updateSettings(
  oldSettings: ISettings,
  name: keyof ISettings,
  value: ISettings[keyof ISettings]
)
```

says:

- `name` is the name of a property of `ISettings`
- `value` is a value of a property of `ISettings`

but doesn't say that it's the same property in both cases, leaving a caller at liberty to write:

```
updateSettings(isettings, "string_property", true);
```

... and that's why the property assignment in the function body is not known to be type correct, and rejected by the compiler.

In contrast, the signature

```
updateSettings<K extends keyof ISettings>(
  oldSettings: ISettings,
  name: K,
  value: ISettings[K]
)
```

says that there is a *single* type `K` among the keys of `ISettings` such that both `name` is of type `K`, and `value` is of type `ISettings[K]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is best possible answer, but I found a solution what works, with generic types. I tested it in vs code and it don't have any problems and also is compiled by typescript without errors and warnings.

```
interface ISettings {
  string_setting: string;
  boolean_setting: boolean;
}

function updateSettings<K extends keyof ISettings>(
  oldSettings: ISettings,
  name: K,
  value: ISettings[K]
): ISettings {
  let newSettings: ISettings = { ...oldSettings };
  newSettings[name] = value;
  return newSettings;
}

const settings: ISettings = null;
const updatedSettings1 = updateSettings(settings, 'boolean_setting', false);
const updaatedSettings2 = updateSettings(settings, 'string_setting', 'string value');
```

**Update 1**
Also if it is not evidently, this function can be write not only for this ISettings interface, but for only object. (`T extends {}` is not necessarily, but I don't think you will want to overwrite something from not an object value)

```
interface ISettings {
  string_setting: string;
  boolean_setting: boolean;
}

function updateObject<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(
  object: T,
  key: K,
  value: T[K]
): T {
  return { ...object, [key]: value };
}

const initial: ISettings = null;
const updated0: ISettings = updateObject(initial, 'string_setting', 'string value'); // ok
const updated1: ISettings = updateObject(initial, 'string_setting', 123); // error
const updated2: ISettings = updateObject(initial, 'boolean_setting', true); // ok
const updated3: ISettings = updateObject(initial, 'boolean_setting', 'not a boolean value'); // error
```

**Update 2:**
And if your function have different type for input object and response you can write it in this form (but I'm not sure if it can be write without any, at least I don't know how)

```
interface ISettings {
  string_setting: string;
  number_settings: number;
  boolean_setting: boolean;
}

function updateObject<T extends {}, K extends keyof T, V>(
  object: T,
  key: K,
  value: V
): V extends T[K] ? T : Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Record<K, V> {
  return { ...object, [key]: value } as any;
}

const initial: ISettings = null;
const updated0 = updateObject(initial, 'string_setting', 'string value'); // type is: ISettings
const updated1 = updateObject(initial, 'string_setting', 123); // type is: Pick<ISettings, "boolean_setting" | "number_settings"> & Record<"string_setting", number>
const updated2 = updateObject(initial, 'boolean_setting', true); // type is: ISettings
const updated3 = updateObject(initial, 'boolean_setting', 'not a boolean value'); // type is: Pick<ISettings, "string_setting" | "number_settings"> & Record<"boolean_setting", string>
```

Comment: The only thing I was able to think of was creating overloads. +1

Comment: interesting, this does solve the immediate error. It does lead to a different error upstream in my full code, which of course you'd have no chance to know. So I think I still need to understand the *why* behind this to fix my non-simplified example. I don't understand why this change would fix the error, and I can't tell right now whether it's correct or just pushing the problem upstream.

Comment: You are getting the error because `value` is a string or a boolean, but `newSetting[name]` is only one of those, it can't be either because your interface says so. For experimentation, make each item in your interface `string | boolean` the error goes away because now you say it can be both. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @MadScientist I'm not sure if it was the reason of problems that you have, but I added an new update, hope it will help you